# problem package broken cant install update

Tags: software-installation, lazarus

after try to install lazarus free pascal

```
broken packages
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/fp-units-rtl-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_i386.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/fpc/3.0.0/units/i386-linux/rtl/si_c21g.ppu', which is also in package fpc 3.0.0
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/fp-compiler-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_i386.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/fpc/3.0.0/ppc386', which is also in package fpc 3.0.0
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/fp-units-base-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_i386.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/fpc/3.0.0/units/i386-linux/ncurses/ocrt.o', which is also in package fpc 3.0.0
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/fp-units-fcl-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_i386.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/fpc/3.0.0/units/i386-linux/fcl-passrc/paswrite.ppu', which is also in package fpc 3.0.0
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/fp-units-gtk2-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_i386.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/fpc/3.0.0/units/i386-linux/cairo/cairoft.o', which is also in package fpc 3.0.0
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/fpc-source-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_all.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.0.0/rtl/android/jvm/java_sys_android.inc', which is also in package fpc-src 3.0.0
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/fp-utils-3.0.0_3.0.0+dfsg-2_i386.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/fpc/3.0.0/units/i386-linux/utils-lexyacc/lexlib.o', which is also in package fpc 3.0.0
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` to see if it will fix the issues

Comment: Also .. are you trying to install 32bit? ... most everything now is 64bit and it may be that you are trying to overwrite the 64bit versions with 32bit ones. This may be actually correct but its unusual for me to see i386 on packages now a days.

Comment: Please paste the entire output including your command you're using when the error is output.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type

```
sudo su

dpkg --configure -a

apt -f install

apt update

apt upgrade

apt autoremove
```

Hope it helps